# Continue to next breakpoint in RubyMine

Tags: debugging, breakpoints, rubymine

I couldn't find any key in RubyMine that **continues execution to next breakpoint**.

I can see **run to cursor**, **step into**, **step over**, etc.

Can anyone suggest how can I **run to next breakpoint**?

Answer (score 0):

To proceed to the next breakpoint, click **Resume Program** on the left toolbar.[image]